# ¿Como puedo cortar el código en caso de que el usuario ponga "no" en mi confirm?

Tags: javascript

Quiero que todo lo que venga después en mi código solo se ejecute en caso de que el usuario ponga confirm. En caso de que ponga que no, quiero que se corte.

```
var avanzar = confirm("Esta seguro que desea avanzar?");
    var hachedos = document.querySelector("h2")

if (avanzar==true) {
  hachedos.innerHTML = "Qué alegría que das con tu visita por este maravilloso sitio!!!"

} else {
  hachedos.innerHTML = "Lamentamos que no quieras continuar tu visita por este maravilloso sitio"
};
```

Esto es lo que quiero que no se corra en caso de que pongamos "no".
Pero que si se corra en caso de "si"

```
var nombre = prompt("Ingrese su nombre");

var hacheuno = document.querySelector("h1");

hacheuno.innerHTML = "Bienvenido " + nombre;

var edad = prompt("Indique su edad");

if (edad<18) {

  var containerGen = document.querySelector(".container-general") ;
    containerGen.style.display = "none";

  var containerOc = document.querySelector(".contenido-bloqueado");
    containerOc.style.display = "initial";
}
```

Comment: Así como esta es funcional, ¿qué es lo que no te esta resultando?

Comment: funciona perfecto, pero quiero que en caso de que el usuario coloque "no" en avanzar, se cambie mi h2, pero ademas (esta es mi consulta) lo que sigue en mi codigo (no lo subi) no se ejecute.

Comment: Entonces por favor deberías subir tu código completo para comprender mejor tu problema, pues yo replique tu ejercicio y si hago click en NO el h2 cambia su valor por el que escribiste en tu código, por favor :D

Comment: @Aprendiz ya lo actualice, fijate si me podes ayudar ahora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes resolver el problema incluyendo el código que quieres ejecutar en el bloque `if`.
Entonces si el usuario coloca "no", se ejecutará solamente el bloque `else`.

El código completo quedaría:

```
var avanzar = confirm("Esta seguro que desea avanzar?");
var hachedos = document.querySelector("h2")

if (avanzar) {
    hachedos.innerHTML = "Qué alegría que das con tu visita por este maravilloso sitio!!!";

    var nombre = prompt("Ingrese su nombre");
    var hacheuno = document.querySelector("h1");
    hacheuno.innerHTML = "Bienvenido " + nombre;
    var edad = prompt("Indique su edad");
    if (edad<18) {
        var containerGen = document.querySelector(".container-general") ;
        containerGen.style.display = "none";

        var containerOc = document.querySelector(".contenido-bloqueado");
        containerOc.style.display = "initial"
    };
} else {
    hachedos.innerHTML = "Lamentamos que no quieras continuar tu visita por este maravilloso sitio"
};
```

Comment: El tipo de valor de confirm es `boolean`, entonces esta línea `if (avanzar==true) {` pudiera quedar solo como `if (avanzar) {`

Comment: Actualizado según tu comentario @Aprendiz. Gracias.

Comment: claro, queria saber si existia alguna forma alternativa, en lugar de meter todo el codigo que sigue entre el ´if´ y el ´else´

Comment: Podés armar una función con ese código y luego invocarla desde el `if`. ¿Esa alternativa te puede servir?

Answer (score 0):

Una solución que podrías aplicar es:

- Meter todo el código dentro de una función o una [Expresión de función ejecutada inmediatamente (`IIFE`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/IIFE)
- y hacer un `return;` en los casos donde necesites que no avance con las siguientes instrucciones.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
(function() {
  var avanzar = confirm("Esta seguro que desea avanzar?");
  var hachedos = document.querySelector("h2")

  if (!avanzar) {
    hachedos.innerHTML = "Lamentamos que no quieras continuar tu visita por este maravilloso sitio"
    return; // AQUI cortamos la ejecución
  }

  hachedos.innerHTML = "Qué alegría que das con tu visita por este maravilloso sitio!!!"

  var nombre = prompt("Ingrese su nombre");
  var hacheuno = document.querySelector("h1");

  hacheuno.innerHTML = "Bienvenido " + nombre;

  var edad = prompt("Indique su edad");
  if (edad < 18) {

    var containerGen = document.querySelector(".container-general");
    containerGen.style.display = "none";

    var containerOc = document.querySelector(".contenido-bloqueado");
    containerOc.style.display = "initial"
    return;
  }
  
  // AQUI lo que sea para >=18
})()
```

```html
<h2></h2>
<h1></h1>
<div class="container-general"></div>
<div class="container-bloqueado"></div>
```